# How to obtain the value of a checkbox in capybara?

Tags: cucumber, capybara

I want to check if a checkbox is checked using cucumber and capybara. I have checked the checkbox in my previous step and want to verify it by obtaining the value of the checkbox.

Answer (score 66, accepted):

Use the `checked?` method

e.g.:

```
my_box = find('#some_checkbox')
my_box.should be_checked  # Before Rspec 2.11

# OR using new syntax
expect(my_box).to be_checked  # Rspec 2.11
```

Comment: If you want to use labels like you can with `check`, you can do: `expect(find(:checkbox, "My Label")).to be_checked`

Answer (score 3):

This one work for me

```
assert page.has_checked_field?('your_checkbox_id')
assert page.has_no_checked_field?('your_checkbox_id')
```

Answer (score 1):

## oneliner using minitest

```
require 'test/unit'
include Test::Unit::Assertions

Then(/^the checkbox "(.*?)" is enabled$/) do |check_box|

  assert_equal(has_checked_field?(check_box), true, 'checkbox not found or checked') 

end
```